# Start ngrok with custom subdomain

Tags: ngrok

Let's say I have a sub domain for example *cute design*. Now I want to create a webserver that has the following subdomain. Is it possible to auto start ngrok every time with this subdomain?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using windows you can just create a batch file that auto starts ngrok with your port and subdomain ready to go.

Just save a document called cutedesign.bat in the same directory that you have ngrok.exe located with 1 line in it like this:

```
ngrok http --subdomain=cutedesign {yourport}
```

It is not included in free plan.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite <your-custom-local-domain>:<port>`

e.g.
`ngrok http --host-header=rewrite mysubdomain:3000`

Comment: Just a small correction, it's `--host-header` with a double leading dash.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX

Create an alias

`alias ngrok='function _ngrok(){ ngrok http -subdomain=cutedesign $1; };_ngrok'`